# Calculate and Display existing Total value with 2 tax percentages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing javascript that calculates a total based on a series of arrays.  The script then places the total in an input field like this: `<input name="total" type="text" class="total" onfocus="this.form.elements[0].focus()" size="10">`

How do I add two additional  values that takes the Total and displays the value with 6% and 7% tax calculated?

```
function calculatetotal() {
    var order_total = new Number();
    order_total = 0;
    var item_price = new Number();
    var item_quantity = new Number();

    // Run through all the form fields
    for (var i=0; i < document.form1.elements.length; ++i) {


        // Get the current field
        form_field = document.form1.elements[i];

        // Get the field's name
        form_name = form_field.name;

        // Is it a "category" field?

        if (form_name.substring(0,3) == "CAT") {
            var adjust_check = check_price_adjustment(form_name);
            if (adjust_check) {
                item_price = form_field.value;
            } else {
                item_price = 0;
            }
        } else if (form_name.substring(0,4) == "PROD") { // Is it a "product" field?
            // Is the major category of this product checked?
            var category = "CAT_" + form_name.substring(5,7);
            var cat_box = document.getElementById(category);
            if (cat_box.type=="checkbox" && cat_box.checked) {
                // If so, extract the price from the form field value
                item_price = form_field.value;
                // reset negative item prices to 0
                if (item_price < 0) {
                    item_price = 0;
                }
            } else if (cat_box.type.indexOf("select")!=-1) {
                // If so, extract the price from the form field value
                item_price = form_field.value;
                // reset negative item prices to 0
                if (item_price < 0) {
                    item_price = 0;
                }
            } else {
                // Price is set to zero
                item_price = 0;
            }
        } else {
            item_price = 0;
        }         

 // Get the quantity
        if (form_field.type=="checkbox") {
            if (form_field.checked) {
                item_quantity = 1;
            } else {
                item_quantity = 0;
            }
        } else if (form_field.type.indexOf("select")!=-1) {
              item_quantity = 1;
        } else if (form_field.type=="hidden") {
            item_quantity = 1;
        }
        if (form_name == "CAT_EX")
             item_price = 0;        


 // Update the order total
        if (item_quantity >= 0) {
                order_total += item_quantity * item_price;
        }
    }

    // Display the total rounded to two decimal places
    document.form1.total.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
}
```

Comment: How about posting some *relevant* code?

Comment: This calculates the total I thought?  What are you looking for?

Comment: It's more like what are *you* looking for? Do you have a problem with your Javascript code? Where's the input, where's the HTML source, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this in JS if this is an actual commercial app.  You should perform calculations in PHP from the DB so that they cannot be manipulated via the DOM.

Comment: It already works exactly how its supposed to for internal use.  Instead of outputting to an <input> field how would I but this value to a php echo maybe?  document.form1.total.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2);

Answer (score 0):

I added additional form elements with calculations here:

```
document.form1.total.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
document.form1.totalsix.value = order_total * .085; 
document.form1.totalseven.value = round_decimals(order_total * .09, 2);
```

And then added the following inputs:

```
<p>$<input name="totalsix" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.form.elements[0].focus()" size="10"></p>
<p>$<input name="totalseven" type="text" value="" onfocus="this.form.elements[0].focus()" size="10"></p>
```